# Need help to parse a complex JSON

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, ios

I´m trying to parse a complex json (using the Json framework), the problem is that the json has a lot of nested objects. Took too much time programming and i can´t find the solution, my code smells and i have a lot of crashes.
Any idea? (i don´t have any problem on using another json framework, like jsonkit or another)

Here is a simplified version of the json.

```
[
{
    "category": {
        "id": 451,
        "description": "Product description",
        "quantity": "3149",
        "category": [
            {
                "category": {
                    "id": 115,
                    "description": "Product description",
                    "quantity": "465",
                    "category": [
                        {
                            "category": {
                                "id": 125,
                                "description": "Product description",
                                "quantity": "6"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "category": {
                                "id": 120,
                                "description": "Product description",
                                "quantity": "57",
                                "category": [
                                    {
                                        "category": {
                                            "id": 193,
                                            "description": "Product description",
                                            "quantity": "27"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "category": {
                                            "id": 194,
                                            "description": "Product description",
                                            "quantity": "14"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "category": {
                                "id": 446,
                                "description": "Product description",
                                "quantity": "7"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "category": {
                                "id": 132,
                                "description": "Product description",
                                "quantity": "28",
                                "category": [
                                    {
                                        "category": {
                                            "id": 224,
                                            "description": "Product description",
                                            "quantity": "3"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "category": {
                                            "id": 137,
                                            "description": "Product description",
                                            "quantity": "4"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "category": {
                                "id": 128,
                                "description": "Product description",
                                "quantity": "21"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "category": {
                    "id": 21,
                    "description": "Product description",
                    "quantity": "225",
                    "category": [
                        {
                            "category": {
                                "id": 170,
                                "description": "Product description",
                                "quantity": "1"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "category": {
                                "id": 68,
                                "description": "Product description",
                                "quantity": "45",
                                "category": [
                                    {
                                        "category": {
                                            "id": 81,
                                            "description": "Product description",
                                            "quantity": "2"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "category": {
                                            "id": 69,
                                            "description": "Product description",
                                            "quantity": "2"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "category": {
        "id": 390,
        "description": "Product description",
        "quantity": "251",
        "category": [
            {
                "category": {
                    "id": 714,
                    "description": "Product description",
                    "quantity": "0"
                }
            },
            {
                "category": {
                    "id": 622,
                    "description": "Product description",
                    "quantity": "22",
                    "category": [
                        {
                            "category": {
                                "id": 192,
                                "description": "Product description",
                                "quantity": "16"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "category": {
                                "id": 391,
                                "description": "Product description",
                                "quantity": "6"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "category": {
                    "id": 612,
                    "description": "Product description",
                    "quantity": "5"
                }
            },
            {
                "category": {
                    "id": 621,
                    "description": "Product description",
                    "quantity": "123",
                    "category": [
                        {
                            "category": {
                                "id": 628,
                                "description": "Product description",
                                "quantity": "25"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "category": {
                                "id": 457,
                                "description": "Product description",
                                "quantity": "3"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "category": {
                    "id": 720,
                    "description": "Product description",
                    "quantity": "1"
                }
            },
            {
                "category": {
                    "id": 188,
                    "description": "Product description",
                    "quantity": "52",
                    "category": [
                        {
                            "category": {
                                "id": 437,
                                "description": "Product description",
                                "quantity": "10"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "category": {
                                "id": 639,
                                "description": "Product description",
                                "quantity": "7"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "category": {
                                "id": 152,
                                "description": "Product description",
                                "quantity": "4",
                                "category": [
                                    {
                                        "category": {
                                            "id": 34,
                                            "description": "Product description",
                                            "quantity": "3"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "category": {
                                            "id": 31,
                                            "description": "Product description",
                                            "quantity": "1"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "category": {
                    "id": 548,
                    "description": "Product description",
                    "quantity": "3"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}]
```

My intention is create an array of objects to populate the database, the table looks like this:

idfather (the father category)
idproduct
description
quantity
timestamp

The last thing i tried:

```
- (void)moreCategories:(NSString *)myString {
    NSLog(@"%@",myString);
    NSDictionary *mydict =[myString valueForKeyPath:@"category"] ;
    NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    myArray = [mydict valueForKey:@"category"] ;
    NSLog(@"count %d",[myArray count]);
    for (int i = 0; i < [myArray count]; i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *dict = [myArray objectAtIndex:i];
//sometime crashes here
        if (dict ){
            //NSLog(@"dict: %d",[dict count]);
            //NSLog(@"id %d",[[dict objectForKey:@"id"] intValue]);
            //NSLog(@"description %@",[dict objectForKey:@"description"] );
            //NSLog(@"quantity %d",[[dict objectForKey:@"quantity"] intValue]);
            if ([dict valueForKeyPath:@"category"]) {
                [self moreCategories:[dict valueForKeyPath:@"category"] ];

            }   
        }
    }

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [connection release];

    NSString *responseString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]autorelease];
    [responseData release];

    NSDictionary *results = [responseString JSONValue]; 
    self.allData = [results valueForKey:@"category"] ;
    NSLog(@"count %d",[self.allData count]);

    for (int i = 0; i < [self.allData count]; i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *dict = [self.allData objectAtIndex:i];
        //NSLog(@"id %d",[[dict objectForKey:@"id"] intValue]);
        NSLog(@"description %@",[dict objectForKey:@"description"] );
        //NSLog(@"quantity %d",[[dict objectForKey:@"quantity"] intValue]);
        if ([dict objectForKey:@"category"]) {
            //NSLog(@"%@",[dict valueForKeyPath:@"category"]);
            //NSLog(@"%@",[self.allData objectAtIndex:i]);
            [self moreCategories:[dict objectForKey:@"category"] ];
            //NSLog(@"%@",[self.allData objectAtIndex:i]);
        }   
    //  NSLog(@"%@",[self.allData objectAtIndex:i]);
    }   

}
```

Comment: You're not telling us exactly what your problem is in any detail. Where's it crashing? For what reason? What's the code look like that's processing this information after it's being returned from json-framework? All these are valid questions that need to be answered before anyone can give you any solid suggestions.

Comment: That JSON sample isn't excessively complex. Any of the JSON libraries should be able to handle that. So the problem isn't in parsing the JSON, the problem is probably in your walking the resultant object. But without some code we'll never know.

Comment: What about key-value coding? It basically solved all my problems with walking JSON data.

Comment: You should check the type of the objects you get back at each step.  (Use `isKindOfClass`, eg.)  This will help you catch misunderstandings about the structure of the data more rapidly.

Comment: Your parameter to `moreCategories` is not an `NSString*`.  You should change the formal type to something else.

Comment: You should be passing the "father" category ID as a parameter in your recursive call.

Comment: Note that a "category" may be an array, or may be a dictionary (if only one element).  You need to test whether the "category" value is an array or not.

Comment: [Actually, on re-examining, I see that there are two different things called "category", dependent on context.]

Comment: [And now I see that this thread is about 10 months old.]

Answer (score 1):

You can use TouchJSON, it's really simple and have good performances. It takes your json as data and can return you a NSArray or an NSDictionnary in one line.

If your JSON have a list structure:

```
NSArray *array = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsArray:yourData error:nil];
```

Else:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:yourData error:nil;
```

You just have to include `TouchJSON` in your project ans import `#import "CJSONDeserializer.h"` in the classes you want to use it. https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem might be the list in the JSON data structure. When I used the JSON framework, I was not able to access array values with keypaths.

I solved the problem on the server side, not allowing arrays in the data structure - only key/value pairs. Then I could access every value in the structure with a keypath from the root node. (I just used numbers up from 0 for the keys when I wanted to transform a list to JSON.)

And are you sure the syntax of the data structure is correct? Maybe your framework can't handle it - although it should be able to. I used this one: https://github.com/stig/json-framework/